# filename of video downloaded using youtube-dl consists of random characters at the end of filename.name

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, filename

There has been a consistent problem with downloading videos from youtube using `youtube-dl`.

The filename has random characters at the end.

e.g, original filename of the video is `Scala Monads: Declutter Your Code With Monadic Design`

but the filename of video after downloading is `Monads - Declutter Your Code With Monadic Design-Mw_Jnn_Y5iA.f136.mp4`

here is the warning during download:

```
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
```

it will be really helpful if somebody could suggest a solution.

Comment: That's the unique string for the video in YouTube url.

Comment: so could we get rid of that somehow?

Comment: What happens with `youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" VIDEO_URL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, use this in your command `-o '%(title)s.%(ext)s'` see here

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template

To set as your default create this folder/file `.config/youtube-dl/config`

Just add the option to that file on single line, info see here

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration